# unity 2d tap to walk

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

1. The speed depends on the distance from the object to the click.
   How to fix that?
2. How to lock the movement (after click) on the y axis?

   ```
   public int speed;
   Vector3 position;
   bool go;

   void FixedUpdate ()
   {      
       if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Mouse0))
       {
           go=true;
           Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
           RaycastHit hit;

           if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
           {
               position = hit.point;
           }
       }

     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       if(go)
       {
           Vector2 direction = position - transform.position;

           float targ_pos = Vector2.Distance (transform.position, position);

           if(targ_pos>0)
           {
               rigidbody2D.AddForce ((position - transform.position)*speed);       
           }
           else {go=false;}
       }  
   }
   ```

Comment: The force that you are currently adding is relative to the distance you are attempting to 'translate'. You need to create a normalized vector and then multiple this by speed.

As for point 2, in your objects rigidbody you can dynamically set movement restraints, i think this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I know about "normalize", but I'm really a newbie. )

Something like: 
rigidbody2D.AddForce ((position - transform.position).Normalize * speed);
causes an errors.

As for point 2 (if you wrote about Constraints lock position/rotation ) this feature available only for RigidBody (3D), not 2D.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're still looking for an answer, but that might help others wondering the same.

I did a game where the character moved with a ClickToMove way. Here's how I did it. My game was 3D so you might have to adjust a little bit.

We store the point we hit, which belongs to the Floor of my scene (floorHit). In the top of my class, I declared a Vector3 toGo. My player has a rigidbody attached to it, which I rotate towards the point its supposed to move. Then use MoveTowards(from,to,speed);

```
if (Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask)) {

                Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;

                // the quaternion defines the rotation, looking through the vector
                Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (playerToMouse);
                playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (newRotation);

                toGo = floorHit.point; // We save the point we touched  }
```

Then outside of the if, still in the update function, we call the MoveTowards with the toGo Vector3 we saved earlier :

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, toGo, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Hope that helps,

On top of that, I have the code if you want to animate your character.

Don't hesitate asking for more,

bRo